# Clearfix breaks the :last-child

Tags: css, css-selectors, clearfix

It's weird but when I use the :last-child to my elements, and then put a clearfix div in the end, it breaks the last-child? Any ideas anyone?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">first child</a>
    <a href="#">second child</a>
    <a href="#">third child</a>
    <a href="#">last/forth child</a>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
     This is after the clearfix
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a{
        display: block;
        margin: 5px;
        color: red;
        width: 80px;
        float: left;
    }

    a:last-child{
        color: blue;
    }

    .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table;
    }
    .clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UBSc3/)

Comment: what result you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to make the last link blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes because that is what `last-child` selector does.
Selects the element that is the **last child of its parent**.

If you add and another `div` after your last `a` this will `div` be the last child of its parent.

```
a:last-child{
    color: blue;
}
```

This selects `a` elements that are last child of its parent.

In this format:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">first child</a>
    <a href="#">second child</a>
    <a href="#">third child</a>
    <a href="#">last/forth child</a>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
     This is after the clearfix
</div>
```

will not select last `a` because it is not the last child of its parent `div`

In the other hand this markup:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">first child</a>
    <a href="#">second child</a>
    <a href="#">third child</a>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <a href="#">last/forth child</a>


     This is after the clearfix
</div>
```

will select the last `a` element.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your "a" tags in a div

```
<div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">first child</a>
        <a href="#">second child</a>
        <a href="#">third child</a>
        <a href="#">last/forth child</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
        This is after the clearfix
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to clear it that way. Try to clearfix on `a`'s container.
 Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UBSc3/4/